# Far away objects are lit by sun lamp when they shouldn't be, moving camera closer to objects they are no longer lit

Tags: eevee-render-engine, lighting

I am creating a forest scene and using the Hosek/Wilkie sky texture in eevee to light the scene. The scene will start with a sunrise, and the sun  starts underneath a plane, with forest stuff on top on it.

When I have my camera close to the trees they are not lit up (as expecpted), however as I move further away the tree models are completely lit up, despite nothing in the scene changing except how close my camera is. The same thing happens whether using the actual camera and rendering images closer/further away, or whether I just move the viewport camera closer/further away in rendered view.

I provide a .blender file with the basics of the scene/problem in it: https://www.mediafire.com/file/lb72l7yr5qiam21/forest+scene+reduced.blend/file

I provide three images.

Image 1 - far away, all trees lit

[image]

Image 2 - mid-range, closer trees notlit, further trees are lit

[image]

Image 3 - closest, no trees are lit

[image]

Many thanks for any help!

Comment: congrats! you uploaded a 781 MB blend file...i am sure you got on the highscore list with this! :D -> would be nice if you could downsize your blend file before uploading to "just" show the problem -> not everybody has a lightning speed internet connection

Comment: Sorry, I did not realize that was possible! How should I go about doing this?

Comment: just by simplifying your scene...delete objects/textures which you don't need to reproduce your problem. But....i already downloaded it....and i could not find the reason for it. Sorry :(